# How can I reload page at every 15 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wolfram-mathematica

I build one web Application in Wolfram Mathematica,what it does it displays the DB data directly on the browser.

I placed my Application in Apache Tomcat.

I want to reload this page for every 15 seconds,because If you reload the page we will get updated data of DB.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please put "javascript reload page" to the google and read the results

Comment: This is an absolute AJAX situation...please refer to passionateCoder's comment

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a script like this in the head section of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout(function(){ document.location.reload(true); }, 15000);
</script>
```

The `setTimeout` method will start the callback after 15 seconds, and the `reload` method will reload the page. The `true` parameter makes the browser always request the page again instead of possibly using a cached version.

Comment: This should read window.setInterval in order to keep the refresh going with some more advanced logic.

Comment: @clops: That would make no difference, as the interval is removed when the page reloads. The new page that is loaded starts its own timeout to reload it again after yet another 15 seconds, and so on.

Comment: My comment was just a suggestion for cases, where you do NOT want to refresh the screen in case some logic should put this process on hold.

Answer (score 8):

That's bad isn't it? Reloading a page once in 15 secs will break the user experience completely. A user will not be able to even read the page properly to get the context in 15 secs.

Why not use `ajax` to get results to update the container which contains the data once in 15 secs? By that you'll give the user updated info.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php", //some server method which will get u new data from database
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  var i= 0;
  for(; i< msg.d.length; i++)
  {
    $("#container").append(msg.d[i]);
  }    
});
```

Where `#container` is where you have the data represented.

`AJAX` Docs : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

Just add `<meta content='15' http-equiv='refresh'/>` between `<head></head>`.  Change the number that you need, like if you need your page to load after 30 secs, then change the value 15 to 30.

```
<head>
<meta content='15' http-equiv='refresh'/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code in the head section of an HTML document will also refresh the page without using any JavaScript:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15" />
```